# How to configure multiple azure SignalR instances in serverless azure functions?

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-function-app, azure-signalr

I want to configure Primary and secondary connection strings of Azure SignalR in azure function.

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetSignalRInfo(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", "api/negotiate")] HttpRequest req,
           [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "chat")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
           ILogger log)
       {
           return connectionInfo;
       }
```

Here with the above code, runtime is always looking for

```
"AzureSignalRConnectionString", but wanted to specify like below.
"AzureSignalRConnectionString:region1:Primary": "connectionstring1",
"AzureSignalRConnectionString:region2:Secondary": "connectionstring2"
```

I read through the documentation and couldn't find anything related to this.

Is there a way to specify multiple azure SignalR connection strings in Serverless function app?